# Page View Controller inside Container, wrong animation when layout if needed

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview, ios-animations

i've created a view with an header and a container... inside the container there is a page view controller

the header resize based on the container, throught an iboutlet constraint

if there is a table view as page in the container then the header resize based on the scroll offset, without animation

if i scroll between pages i want the header to be resized, so i've created a delegate method that listen the end of the scroll animation and then resize the header

but if i animate this resizing with this code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {
    self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = ct
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }, completion: {
     _ in
     if let handler = handler {
         handler()
     }
})
```

then the pages are "reloaded" after the resizing it's complete

this is a video of the animation ( the red background is the background of the page view controller that i've edited for debug reason)

[Video of the Wrong Animation](https://vid.me/sXtR)

Answer (score 0):

Please set constant outside the animation block like this,

```
self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = ct

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: {_ in
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    if let handler = handler {
        handler()
    }
})
```

Comment: please check the constant value, i guess this sould work

Comment: in what way? it's a normal cgfloat, that change based on my algorithym

Comment: check "ct" value it will change as per its value so it can be issue of your algorithm, you can check it by printing "ct"

Comment: and for view animation with constraint you have to set constant value outside the block

Comment: i had seen your video, what you have to do is stop animation then perform swipe, and when you come at the next view dont set animation just set constant value directly

Comment: the step are those

i swipe the page view controller

the delegate method of the page controller, didFinishAnimating, it's performed and there i call a method constraintDelegate ( which is my root view controller ) to set the new constraint height

inside that method it's the bit of code wrote before

so i call the animation after the swipe has endend

Comment: Add **UIView.commitAnimations()** before you call handler check the code